# merge and remove elements in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have this array, i want to merge all elements inside the objects in the nested arrays and remove the duplicates..
the array is the output of mongo db populate so answers from there or just js will be amazing :)

```
 "visitors": [
        [
            {
                "name": "matan",
                "id": "61793e6a0e08cdcaf213c0b1"
            },
            {
                "name": "shani",
                "id": "61793e910e08cdcaf213c0b5"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name": "david",
                "id": "6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23"
            },
            {
                "name": "orit",
                "id": "617986e535fdf4942ef659bd"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name": "david",
                "id": "6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23"
            },
            {
                "name": "orit",
                "id": "617986e535fdf4942ef659bd"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

would like this output -

```
"visitors": [
        {
            "name": "matan",
            "id": "61793e6a0e08cdcaf213c0b1"
        },
        {
            "name": "shani",
            "id": "61793e910e08cdcaf213c0b5"
        },
        {
            "name": "david",
            "id": "6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23"
        },
        {
            "name": "orit",
            "id": "617986e535fdf4942ef659bd"
        },
]
```

these are my collections
i need to get all visitors on one solar system,
so > solars > planets > visitors

```
const solarsModel = new Schema({
    planets: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId ,ref:'planet'} ],
    starName: { type: String, required: true, default: "" }
})

const planetModel = new Schema({
    planetName: { type: String, required: true, default: "" },
    system:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'solar'},
    visitors: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'visitor'}]
})

const visitorModel = new Schema({
    visitorName:{ type: String, required: true, default: "" },
    homePlanet: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"planet" },
    visitedPlanets: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"planet" }]
})
```

this is what i did to achieve a result would love to use Aggregate..

```
  const response = await solarModel
    .findById({ _id: data.id })
    .select({ starName: 1, _id: 0 })
    .populate({
      path: "planets",
      select: { visitors: 1, _id: 0 },
      populate: {
        path: "visitors",
        select: "visitorName",
      },
    })
    .exec();
```

solved with this

```
exports.findVisitorSystemHandler = async (data) => {
  const systemName = await solarModel.findById({ _id: data.id });
  const response = await planetModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { system: makeObjectId(data.id) } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "visitors",
        localField: "visitors",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "solarVisitors",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        solarVisitors: {
          visitedPlanets: 0,
          homePlanet: 0,
          __v: 0,
        },
      },
    },
    { $unwind: "$solarVisitors" },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        system: { $addToSet: systemName.starName },
        solarVisitors: {
          $addToSet: {
            id: "$solarVisitors._id",
            name: "$solarVisitors.visitorName",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    { $unwind: "$system" },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
      },
    },
  ]);
  return response;
};
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide an example of how your final array should look like.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this, but take a look at my answer below and see if it'll work for you. Let me know if you have any questions. Please mark it as the correct answer if it's what you need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` like this:

- `$unwind` twice due to nested array
- `$group` using `$addToSet` to not get duplicates.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$visitors"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$visitors"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "visitors": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "id": "$visitors.id",
          "name": "$visitors.name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/npynQqA5ksf)

Answer (score 0):

#### (1) Flatten the array of arrays

`visitors = visitors.flat();`

Which gives us this:

```
[
  { name: 'matan', id: '61793e6a0e08cdcaf213c0b1' },
  { name: 'shani', id: '61793e910e08cdcaf213c0b5' },
  { name: 'david', id: '6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23' },
  { name: 'orit', id: '617986e535fdf4942ef659bd' },
  { name: 'david', id: '6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23' },
  { name: 'orit', id: '617986e535fdf4942ef659bd' }
]
```

#### (2) Get unique ids

`let uniqueIds= [...new Set(visitors.map(v => v.id)]`

Which gives us this:

```
[
   '61793e6a0e08cdcaf213c0b1',
   '61793e910e08cdcaf213c0b5',
   '6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23',
   '617986e535fdf4942ef659bd'
]
```

#### (3) Get new list of visitors based only on uniqueIds

```
visitors = uniqueIds.map(id => {
   let name = visitors.find(v => v.id === id).name;

   return {
      id,
      name
   }
});
```

Which gives us this:

```
[
  { name: 'matan', id: '61793e6a0e08cdcaf213c0b1' },
  { name: 'shani', id: '61793e910e08cdcaf213c0b5' },
  { name: 'david', id: '6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23' },
  { name: 'orit', id: '617986e535fdf4942ef659bd' },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

- reduce with concat to flatten
- union with an empty array,just to remove duplicates
- if you have other fields except visitors they are not affected

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49b1)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"visitors": 
     {"$setUnion": 
       [{"$reduce": 
         {"input": "$visitors",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}},
        []]}}}])
```

Results

```
[{
  "visitors": [
    {
      "name": "david",
      "id": "6179869cb4944c6b19b05a23"
    },
    {
      "name": "matan",
      "id": "61793e6a0e08cdcaf213c0b1"
    },
    {
      "name": "orit",
      "id": "617986e535fdf4942ef659bd"
    },
    {
      "name": "shani",
      "id": "61793e910e08cdcaf213c0b5"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: visitors array is a very filtered result of a nested populated collections, to work with aggregate i'll have to find a nested collection inside a nested collection of the "grandfather collection", which i would prefer but couldn't find the way to do so..

Comment: if you can give us the whole document, where the visitors is in, or all the query you are making, you can use `$lookup` instead of populate i think

Comment: edited the question with my code

Comment: ok i saw it, i dont use mongoose,you can make all this an aggregation, without find and populate, but with $lookup, $lookup is faster

Comment: How can use lookup twice thou in the same aggregate ?

Comment: there is a $lookup version with pipeline, that allows even nested $lookup , but maybe you dont need nested, maybe you just need 2 $lookup one after the other. Or you can do lookup unwind and second lookup (instead of nested)